# Use Table to set Imported Variable?

Tags: import, list-manipulation, dataset, assignment

I'd like to assign a SemanticImport dataset to a variable on import. 
Right now, I have this, and it doesn't work:

```
monkeynames = 
Unevaluated /@ {Abby, Atlas, BenBob, Bonnie, Chibi};

elmonkey = {Abby, Atlas, BenBob, Bonnie, Chibi};

Table[monkeynames[[i]] = 
SemanticImport[
"(filename)" <> 
 ToString[elmonkey[[i]]] <> ".csv"], {i, 1, 5}];
```

I'd like to assign on import, and I have more than 5 csv files, so doing it by hand is not an option. (Unless it's the only option...)

Comment: I guess you somehow specified `filename`, although this is not done in the code above. Then there still is the obvious mistake that you are trying to import 23 files but your list elmonkey only contains 5 elements so `elmonkey[[i]]` is not defined for `i>5`.

Comment: @Wizard That's fixed, and yes the filename is filled in.

Comment: Try this: `Scan[(Evaluate[Symbol[#]] = SemanticImport["(filename)" <> # <> ".csv"]) &, {"Abby", "Atlas", "BenBob", "Bonnie", "Chibi"}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Wow!! I didn't even know Scan was a function! Thank You, that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is it is trying to set the symbol "monkeynames[[2]]" = some expr, rather than the symbol monkeynames[[2]] evaluates to. Simply wrap monkeynames[[i]] in Evaluate, and it should work.

Final result:

```
monkeynames = 
{Abby, Atlas, BenBob, Bonnie, Chibi};

elmonkey = {Abby, Atlas, BenBob, Bonnie, Chibi};

Table[Evaluate[monkeynames[[i]]] = 
SemanticImport[
"filepath" <> 
ToString[elmonkey[[i]]] <> ".csv"], {i,1,5}];
```

Comment: Though smart, sadly this doesn't work... Putting 'Evaluate' around 'monkeynames[[1]] ' doesn't evaluate it for some reason....

Comment: Sorry, when I was testing this yesterday I was using an example similar to this:
In[1]:= monkeynames = {Abby, Atlas, BenBob, Bonnie, Chibi}

Out[1]= {Abby, Atlas, BenBob, Bonnie, Chibi}

In[2]:= Table[Evaluate[monkeynames[[i]]] = i, {i, 1, 5}];

In[3]:= monkeynames

Out[3]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Where I didn't map Unevaluate over the names list initially. If you wish to use Table to set the values of a list, this should work. Please give it a try, and let me know.

Comment: Yep! That works too!